# DataMapper.get(:attribute => value) returning nil

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

Model:

```
class Country
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :continent, String
end
```

I'm trying to do a query by the name attribute:

`Country.find(:name => "value")`

But it keeps returning me a `nil`. Which should not be the case since I'm very sure that the record with the particular value exist in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized I have to do: `Country.first(:name => "value")` or `Country.last(:name => "value")`

`Country.get` only supports search by primary keys or composite keys

And alternative is: `Country.all(:conditions => { :name => "value" })`

Reference: http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html